Azure Functions root throws double / in route exception upon upgrading to .NET 8 and isolated
EDIT:
I've since found out what was causing the problem, namely the migrate instructions from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8) say to use .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() if you do intend to use HTTP triggers. Changing this to .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults instead allows me to use HTTP triggers without the // limitation

I've had an in process Azure Function project that has worked great. But with the email that went out that I need to upgrade to .NET 8 I had to also move to the isolated worker Azure Function model. Previously I was on .NET 6 with the in process model.
The project seems to have upgraded fine and I got it to run now after making all the additional required changes, but one problem still persists in that I cannot access the root of my project in the browser.
I've had a static page set up on the root using the "AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage": true in local.settings.json and "version": "2.0", "extensions": { "http": { "routePrefix": "" } } in host.json. But now it throws the following exception:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternException: The route template separator character '/' cannot appear consecutively. It must be separated by either a parameter or a literal value.

Removing the / from the route removes the exception, but makes the function not be run upon navigating to the address and is merely returned a HTTP 204 result.
Changing the route to ~/ makes it report back that it is executing the function, but it gets stuck in an endless loop and my function never actually gets called. Breaking off the request from the browser immediately throws a TaskCancelledException.
My static web function simplified looks like this:
public class StaticWebFunctions
{
    [Function(nameof(WebRoot))]
    public IActionResult WebRoot([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "/")] HttpRequest request)
    {
        return new ContentResult() { Content = "Testing root functionality, pun intended" };
    }
}

Is there a way around this limitation that was introduced?

In Route, you need give a value. for example  Route = "test" and Azure function adds "/" automatically . output https://localhost:7071/api/test

what happens when you remove Route parameter?

It will default to using the method name, so in this case it will be '/WebRoot'

The reason the question was closed makes no sense at all in context, but I have found out the reason why it was not working in the meantime.
The migrate instructions from Microsoft say to use .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() if you do intend to use HTTP triggers. Changing this to .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults instead allows me to use HTTP triggers without the // limitation
